# Why is the fact that two sets can be homeomorphic but not isometric implies completeness is not a topological property?

Tags: general-topology

Completeness is not preserved by homeomorphism, but what is the relationship with that and isometric mappings?

Comment: What is your definition of "topological property"? Once you make that precise, it should become fairly immediate.

Comment: I would argue the other way around: since completeness is preserved by isometries but not necessarily by homeomorphisms, two metric spaces can be homeomorphic yet non-isometric. What you actually need for the implication in the title is not only to exhibit non-isometric homeomorphic spaces $X$ and $Y$, but also to choose $X$ complete and $Y$ non-complete

Comment: topological property is defined to be properties preserved under homeomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

By definition a topological peopery is one which is perserved under homeomorphisms. Completeness is not a topological property : $(-1,1)$ with the usual metric is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ with the usual metric under the map $x \to \tan (\frac {\pi} 2 x)$. While $(-1,1)$ is incomplete, the real line is complete. Under an isometric bijection completness is preseved.

Comment: It's worth noting that in the context of metric spaces, all isometric bijections are homeomorphisms but not all homeomorphisms are isometric bijections. So "preserved by isometric bijections" (which completeness *is*) is weaker than "preserved by homeomorphisms" (which completeness *isn't*).

Comment: I think $e^x$ is a simpler example.